# Substracting values of 2 columns in pd.Dataframe not working dynamically while adding does work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a really weird question with my dataframe. I would like to subtract the values from index column 1, from index column 0 (so 'High' - 'Distance from low to top'). But somehow, it returns the same value for all rows. [image]

When I change the - into a +, the value does change dynamically (see screenshots), and the values in index column 2 are changed correctly. [image]

Any idea's on how to fix this?

I tried substracting, using abs, creating two dataframes and using the d1.substract(d2) option, all not working.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, thank you, will do next time.

Comment: Well... the results are just the same. Haven't checked all but the first two are `21888.00 - 4205.27 = 1768.73` and `22527.37 - 4844.64 = 1768.73`

Comment: You can edit your question to include code and data as formated text

Comment: Lol, you are right. Cant believe I didn't see that. Thank you!